# Whats this motif called?

Tags: illustration

I did a google image reverse search and found nothing.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: This is very broad and there's no information, could you please tell us where you found it, what you think it is, what you want to know...

Comment: Ive seen this kind of pattern a lot lately, I guess it's a trend now in graphic design. I just want to know the name, if it has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' a piece of a map - a hill presented as elevation contours. Search for topographic map or contour map.

There are a couple of places where two contours have nearly met. The noise reduction in scanner's image processing easily fills the gap.

Comment: Or it's a wood grain :)

Comment: Can't bring myself to downvote an 18k user, but this is a guess, and the question is unclear

Comment: @mayersdesign Of course it's a guess, because we have no idea where the shape is actually copied from. But topographic maps from non-plain areas really contain much of same looking curve patterns. I'm also sure that some talented person could use those patterns in a creative way to make something interesting and fine looking. 18k in any site is nothing when compared to that capability, which I unfortunately haven't.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @user287001 had it right :) thank you very much